# How to pass & retrieve arguments to a .sh file in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, spawn, spawning

Can we pass arguments to a .sh file in Nodejs, i am trying to Spawn a `.sh` file, and want to pass some arguments while spawning,

```
  var command = spawn(__dirname + "/import.sh", {
    var1: "abc"
  });
```

in the above command i am trying to spawn the file import.sh and also trying to pass arguments along with it, i don't know if it's the correct way
and how to retrieve the variable value in the `import.sh` file?

Comment: Did you read [the fine manual](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i got the answer:

```
var env = Object.create(process.env);
env.var1 = "abc";

var command = spawn(__dirname + "/import.sh", {
    env: env
});
```

and to retrieve this in `import.sh` simply do:

```
if [ ${var1} == "abc" ]
then
    // your code goes here
fi
```

that's it :)

Comment: Been looking for this for way too long! Thank you!!!